# Removing DOM node throws exception Node,removeChild must be an instance of Node

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild

I am trying to remove a html element:

```js
function welcomeBack(user) {

  var loginDiv = document.getElementById("logindiv");
  var login = document.getElementById("loginAnchor");
  loginDiv.removeChild(login);

}
```

The parent and child elements:

```html
<div id="logindiv">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="login()" id="loginAnchor">Sign In</a></li>
</div>
```

However, I am getting th following error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 ('child') to Node.removeChild must be an
>   instance of Node

I have searched for similar issues but can't seem to find a solution or explanation.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: What does `console.log(login)` return? Also, you don't need to use `removeChild()`. It's easier to just use `login.remove()` in your case, without looking up the parent in DOM.

Comment: remove() is a jQuery method. Doesn't look like the OP uses jQuery

Comment: Try: childNode.parentNode.removeChild(childNode) so in your case login.parentNode.removeChild(login)

Comment: `#loginAnchor` is not a child of `#logindiv`; it's a grandchild. Do you want to remove the _parent_ `li` from `#logindiv` or remove `loginAnchor` from its parent `li`? In any case, the error seems to be saying that `document.getElementById("loginAnchor");` is not finding an element.

Comment: That makes sense hadn't thought about the <li> element place in the hierarchy

Comment: @Will loginButton.parentNode.removeChild(loginButton); worked

Answer (score 2):

You need to make reference to the `parentNode` where the `childNode` lives before removing it.

Try this:

```js
function welcomeBack(user) {

  var loginDiv = document.getElementById("logindiv");
  var login = document.getElementById("loginAnchor");
  var loginDiv = login.parentNode; 
  loginDiv.removeChild(login);

}
```